# Problems accessing a variable which is casted into pointer to array of int with ctypes in python

Tags: python, pointers, casting, multidimensional-array, ctypes

I have C code which uses a variable `data`, which is a large 2d array created with malloc with variable size. Now I have to write an interface, so that the C functions can be called from within Python. I use ctypes for that.

C code:

```
FOO* pytrain(float **data){
    FOO *foo = foo_autoTrain((float (*)[])data);
    return foo;
}
```

with

```
FOO *foo_autoTrain(float data[nrows][ncols]) {...}
```

Python code:

```
autofoo=cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")
... data gets filled ...
foo = autofoo.pytrain(pointer(pointer(p_data)))
```

My problem is, that when I try to access `data` in foo_autoTrain I only get `0.0` or other random values and a seg fault later. So how could I pass `float (*)[])data` to foo_autoTrain in Python?

Please don't hesitate to point out, if I described some part of my problem not sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue is a miscomprehension of how multidimensional arrays work in C.  An expression like `a[r][c]` can mean one of two things depending on the type of `a`.  If the type of `a` were `float **`, then the expression would mean a double pointer-offset dereference, something like this if done out long-hand:

```
float *row = a[r]; // First dereference yields a pointer to the row array
return row[c]      // Second dereference yields the value
```

If the type of `a` were instead `float (*)[ncols]`, then the expression becomes simply shorthand for shaping a contiguous, one-dimensional memory region as a multi-dimensional array:

```
float *flat = (float *)a;
return flat[(r * ncols) + c]; // Same as a[r][c]
```

So in your C code, the type of `pytrain()`'s argument should be either `float *` or `float (*)[ncols]` and your Python code should look something like the following (assuming you're using NumPy for your array data):

```
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
autofoo.pytrain.argtypes = [c_float_p]
data = numpy.array([[0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3]], dtype=numpy.float32)
data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
autofoo.pytrain(data_p)
```

And if you are in fact using NumPy, check out the [ctypes page of the SciPy wiki](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes).